# find out how many pairs of number that ...

Tags: number-theory

There is a box with the numbers from 1 to 60 and another box with the numbers from 1 - 60 too. 
There are 60 students. Each of these students go to both box and pick up a number. 
If the product of these two numbers is divisor in 60, they will earn a cola. How many many students will earn a cola?

I have tried to look at the numbers 6 - 12 - 18 - 24 - 30 - 36 - 42 - 48 - 54 - 60 and the divisor in every of these and try to count the numbers of pair of product, which will be a divisor in 60. I got the result 40, but I was wondered about there is a easier way to do it. 
(sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe no students. Call a number "potential" if when it is multiplied by another potential number it is a divisor of $60$. Someone with a potential number from box $1$ and box $2$ gets a cola, but if they don't have two potential numbers they get nothing.

Now let the students all get a number from box $1$. The ones with "potential" numbers could pick up a number from box $2$ without potential. The ones without potential numbers could pick up potential numbers from the second bag. And $\text{potential}\times \text{no potential}=\text{not divisor of 60}$, so no-one gets a cola.

Note that this only works if there are less potential numbers than ones without potential. If $\text{potential numbers}> \text{not potential numbers}$ then at least $\text{potential numbers}- \text{not potential numbers}$ people get a cola.